# Making a Java class thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to understand as to how to make the Java class thread-safe.

```
package com.test;

public class ThreadBean {

    private int x;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Inorder to do this,I need to create another program that spawns the threads(lets say 2 threads) and then each of the two threads sets values using the setX().When the values are being read using getX() I should be able to see inconsistencies thanks to the above ThreadBean class not being threadsafe.This maybe a simplistic case but this is just for my understanding.Please advise.Thanks

Comment: It's explained in the [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html).

Comment: You want to make a class thread  safe or any method? If you want to make any method thread safe you may use synchronized key word. If all the methods are synchronized, then your class will be thread safe.

Comment: Concurrency and multithreading are complex and potentially very difficult topics. You should read tutorials/books on that, not ask questions about tiny aspects thereof.

Comment: Thanks.Will look up the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A class is "thread safe" if there is no way for overlapped calls from different threads to leave any instance of the class in an invalid state, and there is no way for overlapped calls to leave the class's static data in an invalid state.

Your `ThreadBean` class doesn't have any static data, and it has only one instance variable.

What are the possible states of a `ThreadBean` instance?  Which of those states is valid, and which is invalid?  How could overlapped calls to any of the methods leave a `ThreadBean` in an invalid state?  (Hint: assignments to an `int` variable are guaranteed to be atomic.)

---

Your question would be more interesting if your `ThreadBean` had members named `x` and `y`, and some required relationship between them like, `x` must always be less than `y`